# Laravel select is not working with subquery

Tags: mysql, laravel

I was attempting to create a Laravel function to run the following query. But I'm not seeing any improvement. Please help.

```
SELECT leads_followup_status_list.followup_status_name, COUNT(FUP.followup_status) FROM `leads_enquiry_details` LEFT JOIN (SELECT max(followup_id) as FID,leads_enquiry_details_enquiry_id  as LID,leads_followup_details.followup_comment,followup_date,followup_status from leads_followup_details WHERE leads_followup_details.followup_deleted=1 GROUP by LID )fup on leads_enquiry_details.enquiry_id=fup.LID  JOIN leads_followup_status_list on leads_followup_status_list.followup_status_id =FUP.followup_status where leads_enquiry_details.enquiry_deleted=1 and leads_enquiry_details.enquiry_status=1 GROUP by FUP.followup_status
```

This is my function

```
 public function getFollowupStatusCount($parametr=null){
    
            $status_counts = LeadsDetails::where('enquiry_deleted', '=', 1)
                ->where('enquiry_status', 1)
                ->leftjoin(DB::raw('(SELECT max(followup_id) as FID,leads_enquiry_details_enquiry_id  as LID,
                leads_followup_details.followup_comment,
                followup_date,followup_status from leads_followup_details  GROUP by LID )
                   FUP'),
                    function($leftjoin)
                    {
                        $leftjoin->on('leads_enquiry_details.enquiry_id', '=', 'fup.LID');
                    })
                ->leftjoin('leads_followup_status_list.followup_status_id','leads_followup_status_list','fup.followup_status')
    
                ->select('COUNT(FUP.followup_status) as count',  'leads_followup_status_list.followup_status_name as status',
                    'leads_followup_status_list.followup_status_color_code as color')
                ->groupBy('followup_status');
    
    
    
    
            return $status_counts;
        }
```

Comment: do you get any errors? Looks like you're missing `->get()` at the end of the query.

Comment: No i tried to display by using DD. Then i get        
     Builder {#321 ▼
  #query: Builder {#289 ▶}
  #model: LeadsDetails {#293 ▶}
  #eagerLoad: []
  #localMacros: []
  #onDelete: null
  #passthru: array:13 [▶]
  #scopes: []
  #removedScopes: []
}

Comment: Try adding `->get()` to the end of the statement

Comment: Thanks bro.. I tried but that also not working.. SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'leads_followup_status_list.followup_status_id' doesn't exist (SQL: select `COUNT(FUP`.`followup_status)` as `count`, `leads_followup_status_list`.`followup_status_name` as `status`, `leads_followup_status_list`.`followup_status_color_code` as `color` from `leads_enquiry_details` left join (SELECT max(followup_id) as

Comment: but this followup_status_id is there in that table

Comment: I think you need to swap arguments 1 and 2 on the second left join:             -`leftjoin('leads_followup_status_list', 'leads_followup_status_list.followup_status_id','fup.followup_status')`

Comment: Thanks .. LOL ..I didn't see that yet.. Let me try that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I've noticed 2 problems. First, you miss `->get()` at the end of you request. Second, your parameters order is wrong on second leftJoin. Should be:

```
->leftJoin('leads_followup_status_list',
'leads_followup_status_list.followup_status_id', '=', 'fup.followup_status')
```

Should work after these fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much @Pavel Lint, There were one mistake too . I should have used  select( **DB::raw('count(FUP.followup_status)** as count'),' instead of count..